# If abstract base class contains parameterised constructor (and derived does not) why can't it be used?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, constructor, domain-driven-design

I have a DDD type solution with "domain model" classes which are constructed using a "DTO" class (i.e. raw data from DB).

The domain model classes all inherit from an abstract base class, which is intended to provide generic injecting/retrieving of the DTO data. Here is a sample:

```
public abstract class DomainModelBase<T> where T : IDto, new()
{
    protected T _data;

    protected DomainModelBase()
    {
        _data = new T();
    }

    protected DomainModelBase(T data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    protected void SetData(T data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    public T GetData()
    {
        return _data;
    }
}

public class AttributeOption : DomainModelBase<AttributeOptionData>
{
    //public AttributeOption(AttributeOptionData data)
    //{
    //    SetData(data);
    //}
}
```

I thought (because DomainModelBase contains a parameterised constructor) I would be able to do this:

```
        var data = new AttributeOptionData();
        var model = new AttributeOption(data);
```

However, the compiler says "Constructor 'AttributeOption' has zero parameters, but is invoked with one argument". The only way to make it work seems to be to create a parameterised constructor in the derived class (like the commented out one above).

Is there a way to make this work by modifying the base class, i.e. without the work of setting up parameterised constructors in every derived class?

Comment: Constructors aren't inherited. See marked duplicate for Stack Overflow citation, and of course the C# documentation and specification for official citation. This is clearly described in the language manuals, references, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.

It's a limitation that says 'each derived class should use (implicitly or explicitly) at least one constructor from base class.

In your example, your child class implicitly has parameterless constructor which implicitly uses parameterless constructor from base.

So, you need to: either setup parameretised constructor in every derived class or delele this constructor from base class.

Or, you can try something like that:

```
public class AttributeOption : DomainModelBase<AttributeOptionData>
{
    public AttributeOption(AttributeOptionData data) : base(data) { }
}
```

That's not what you exactly want, but that what we have.